# NoMethodError for Best In Place gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, best-in-place

I'm trying to implement the [Best In Place](https://github.com/bernat/best_in_place) gem and have followed along with the [Railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/302-in-place-editing), but am having issues. I'm learning Rails and am building a sample blog app with two models, `Article` and `Comment`. I'm trying to use Best In Place to edit comments.

**_list_comments.html.erb**

```
<% @comments.each do |comment| %>
    <hr />

    <%= link_to article_comment_path(@article, comment), method: :delete, data: {confirm: 'Are you sure?'}, remote: true do %>
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>
    <% end %>
    <%= content_tag :span, '', id: "#{comment.id}", class: "glyphicon glyphicon-edit edit_comment" %>       

    <!--<%= content_tag :p, content_tag(:small, "#{comment.author}"), id: "comment_author_#{comment.id}" %>-->
    <%= best_in_place comment, :author %>
    <%= content_tag :p, id: "comment_body_#{comment.id}" do %>
        <%= comment.body %>
    <% end %>

<% end %>
```

It is giving me this error: `ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method comment_path for #<#<Class:0x007fdc38fb8288>:0x007fdc38fc36b0>):`, which is referring to `<%= best_in_place comment, :author %>`. I'm pretty sure I installed everything correctly, so I don't know what the problem is.

When I change `<%= best_in_place comment, :author %>` to `<%= best_in_place "#{comment}", :author %>`, it gives me this error: `undefined method 'author' for "#<Comment:0x007fdc3c841820>":String`.

**comments_controller.html.erb**

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
    def create
        @comment = Comment.new(comment_params)
        @comment.article_id = params[:article_id]
        if @comment.save
            respond_to do |f|
                f.html { redirect_to article_path(params[:article_id]), notice: 'Comment created!' }
                f.js { 
                    @article = Article.find(params[:article_id])
                    @comment = @comment
                    @comments = Comment.where(article_id: params[:article_id])
                }
            end
        else
            redirect_to article_path(params[:article_id]), warning: 'Unable to create comment.'
        end
    end

    def destroy
        @comment = Comment.find(params[:id]).destroy
        respond_to do |f|
            f.html { redirect_to article_path(params[:article_id]) }
            f.js { 
                @article = Article.find(params[:article_id])
                @comments = Comment.where(article_id: params[:article_id])
            }
        end
    end

    def update
        @comment = Comment.find(params[:id])
        if @comment.update(comment_params)
            respond_to do |f|
                f.html { redirect_to article_path(@comment.article_id) }
                f.json { render head :ok}
            end
        else
            respond_to do |f|
                f.html { redirect_to article_path(@comment.article_id) }
                f.json { render json: @comment.errors.full_messages, status: :unprocessable_entity }
            end
        end
    end

    private

        def comment_params
            params.require(:comment).permit(:author, :body)
        end
end
```

Comment: Change `<!--<%=` to `<!--<%#=` to not perform this string. It would not help with your problem i think, but anyway.

Comment: @zishe just tried it and it led to the same error.

Comment: which line is the error message pointing to? which file is rendering the partial?

Comment: @WaliAli `<%= best_in_place comment, :author %>`. I'll update the question to clarify this.

Comment: and if you remove `best_in_place` from that line and replace it with `<%= comment.author %>`, you are no longer getting the error? that code in that line looks correct to me

Comment: try this: in your `update` action, substitute `f.json { render head :ok}` with `format.json { respond_with_bip(@comment) }`. I wonder if that would make a difference. restart the server

Comment: `articles/show.html.erb` is rendering the partial.

Comment: post your routes code. I think the error message has more to do with your routes setup

Comment: `root 'articles#index'
 resources :articles do
  resources :comments
 end`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54358/discussion-between-adam-zerner-and-wali-ali).

Comment: @WaliAli https://github.com/adamzerner/blog

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to clone your project and figure out why you are getting this error:

```
undefined method comment_path for #<#<Class:0x007fdc38fb8288>:0x007fdc38fc36b0>
```

Here is what's happening. In this code `<%= best_in_place comment, :author %>`, you are passing `comment` object. `best_in_place` is trying to map it to a route helper named `comment_path` by appending path to comment (hint: undefined method `comment_path`).

Your routes are set up this way:

```
resources :articles do
    resources :comments
end
```

if you do rake routes, you'll notice that you don't have a helper path named `comment_path` which corresponds to your `comments#show`. It is looking for `comment_path` and it can't find it. hence, the error message.

However, since you are using nesting resources the helper path that corresponds to the `comments#show` is called `article_comment_path`. here is the complete mapping:

```
article_comment_path GET /articles/:article_id/comments/:id(.:format) comments#show
```

To get `best_in_place` map to the correct helper path, there are two ways you can solve this:

1) create a route that maps to `comment_path` by simply adding this route to your `routes.rb` file:

```
resources :comments, only: [:show]
```

The full mapping for the above route is:

```
comment_path GET /comments/:id(.:format) comments#show
```

you now have `comment_path`. No more error message.

2) Tweak your code to map to `article_comment_path`

replace:

```
<%= best_in_place comment, :author %>
```

with:

```
<%= best_in_place [@article, comment], :author %>
```

The array, `[@article, comment]`, will build the helper path `article_comment_path` by appending comment to @article